# How to create database table from sequelizejs model definition?

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

There are several models defined with `sequelizejs` for my nodejs project. Here is an example of Event model in `event.js`:

```
const Event = db.define('event', {
    id: {type: Sql.INTEGER,
         primaryKey:true,
         min: 1},
    name: {type: Sql.STRING,
           min:2,
           allowNull: false,
        }, 
    event_info: {type: Sql.JSON},
    current_step: {type: Sql.STRING},
    customer_id: {type: Sql.INTEGER},
    access_list: {type: Sql.JSON},
    event_snapshot: {type: Sql.JSON},
    event_category_id: {type: Sql.INTEGER,
            },
    status: {type: Sql.STRING,
             isIn: ['active', 'cancelled', 'aborted', 'completed']},
    last_updated_by_id: {type: Sql.INTEGER},
    createdAt: Sql.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sql.DATE
});
```

Is there a way I can create the `event` table out of the `event.js` in command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it as @Chase mentioned but in my humble opinion, you should have split files for models and migrations.

This way you will have your current state of models represented in the model files (like the one you have) and the historical state of your database in [Migration](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html) files.

Syncing will always drop any tables that exist and create them from scratch using the models. The mentioned solution will indeed create the table or update it (thought it will be doing a drop and then a create) but you will lose all data in the process. Migrations are generally preferred.

Comment: It will only drop tables if `options.force` is set to true in `sync()`, otherwise sequelize will create the table if it does not exists, in case the table is already present then it will ignore the schema changes.

Answer (score 2):

You could, if you instantiate Sequelize and call [sync](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-sync) in your `event.js` script as well.